# 15.04 ASPIRE 5750g WIFI connected but doesn't work

Tags: networking, wireless, drivers, 15.04

I have a problem with my PC, it is connected via wifi but the browser doesn't load web pages. With Windows 7 the problem persists, so it is maybe a hardware problem. How i can check this? Other wireless device connected at the same network works fine. I have formatted the computer and resetted the router.

Router model: sitecom N300 x4
computer: acer aspire 5750g (ubuntu 15.04 / windows 7)

If I used a wired connection (ethernet) it works well.

Here is some information:

```
   *-network
        description: Wireless interface
        product: BCM43227 802.11b/g/n
        vendor: Broadcom Corporation
        physical id: 0
        bus info: pci@0000:03:00.0
        logical name: wlan0
        version: 00
        serial: cc:af:78:00:a9:48
        width: 64 bits
        clock: 33MHz
        capabilities: pm msi pciexpress bus_master cap_list ethernet physical wireless
        configuration: broadcast=yes driver=wl0 driverversion=6.30.223.248 (r487574) ip=192.168.0.105 latency=0 multicast=yes wireless=IEEE 802.11abg
        resources: irq:17 memory:d1900000-d1903fff
```

ifconfig:

```
eth0      Link encap:Ethernet  IndirizzoHW b8:70:f4:a7:06:e1  
          UP BROADCAST MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:37349 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:27138 errors:2 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisioni:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          Byte RX:49011831 (49.0 MB)  Byte TX:2794589 (2.7 MB)
          Interrupt:16 
lo        Link encap:Loopback locale  
          indirizzo inet:127.0.0.1  Maschera:255.0.0.0
          indirizzo inet6: ::1/128 Scope:Host
          UP LOOPBACK RUNNING  MTU:65536  Metric:1
          RX packets:4401 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:4401 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisioni:0 txqueuelen:0 
          Byte RX:429507 (429.5 KB)  Byte TX:429507 (429.5 KB)
wlan0     Link encap:Ethernet  IndirizzoHW cc:af:78:00:a9:48  
          indirizzo inet:192.168.0.105  Bcast:192.168.0.255  Maschera:255.255.255.0
          indirizzo inet6: fe80::ceaf:78ff:fe00:a948/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:16057 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:60879
          TX packets:12755 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisioni:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          Byte RX:17888304 (17.8 MB)  Byte TX:1376251 (1.3 MB)
          Interrupt:17
```

route -n

```
Tabella di routing IP del kernel
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
0.0.0.0         192.168.0.1     0.0.0.0         UG    1024   0        0 wlan0
169.254.0.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.0.0     U     1000   0        0 wlan0
192.168.0.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     0      0        0 wlan0
```

ping -c 4 8.8.8.8

```
PING 8.8.8.8 (8.8.8.8) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from 8.8.8.8: icmp_seq=4 ttl=54 time=48.3 ms

--- 8.8.8.8 ping statistics ---
4 packets transmitted, 1 received, 75% packet loss, time 3022ms
rtt min/avg/max/mdev = 48.323/48.323/48.323/0.000 ms
```

ping -c google.com

```
PING google.com (173.194.113.232) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from mil01s18-in-f8.1e100.net (173.194.113.232): icmp_seq=1 ttl=55 time=45.7 ms
64 bytes from mil01s18-in-f8.1e100.net (173.194.113.232): icmp_seq=3 ttl=55 time=46.3 ms
64 bytes from mil01s18-in-f8.1e100.net (173.194.113.232): icmp_seq=4 ttl=55 time=46.5 ms

--- google.com ping statistics ---
4 packets transmitted, 3 received, 25% packet loss, time 7066ms
rtt min/avg/max/mdev = 45.732/46.236/46.598/0.367 ms
```

EDIT: if i don't open youtube the connection is more stable and it stay connected for a long time, but if i open a video o something like it stop to load new pages.

Comment: Please append the output of `sudo iwconfig wlan0`

Answer (score 1):

If this problem persists in Windows, it is not an Ubuntu problem. It is either a hardware problem, or a problem with your wireless environment, or just low signal strength.

Try to get closer to your router. And also changing a channel in your router settings may solve that problem, if there are too many wireless networks using that channel in your neighborhood.

Comment: The problem persist also if i'am closer to the ruter and if this is the only device connected. I don't know if is an hw problem because sometime internet work but just for a minute and then stop to work.